# active admin capitalize the first letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My question is simple but I didn't find the answer for it!
How to capitalize the first letter in active admin

For example I tried these two but none of them are working

```
index do
    column :first_name.upcase
    column :last_name.capitalize
```

I dont have error but they give me blank input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

column accepts block, so you can do it like:

```
  column "First name" do |user|
    link_to user.first_name.capitalize, admin_user_path(user)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Column accepts block and you can customise the column label by sending the string within quotes. Try the below code if you want the label to be "First Name".

```
index do
  column "First Name" do |user|
    user.first_name
  end
  #other columns
end
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.